# perl crashed by Memoize::Storable

Tags: perl

The following code (most from Memoize home page) creates a file with 0 bytes and afterwards perl crashes with exit code -1073741819. 
I tested this with ActivePerl 5.10 and the newest 5.16 version.

```
use Memoize;
use Memoize::Storable;

sub ttt { return 44; }
tie my %cache => 'Memoize::Storable', 'ttt.store';
memoize 'ttt', SCALAR_CACHE => [HASH => \%cache];
```

This happens on two diff computers under Win XP. Any Ideas?

Comment: Also crashed Perl on Win7 SP1 with ActiveState 5.14.2, Memoize 1.03.

Comment: Also crashes on 5.18.0 - [stacktrace](http://paste.scsys.co.uk/257896?tx=on) –– amprz2, you should [report](http://p3rl.org/perlbug) this crash bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly `unmemoize` the subroutine when you have finished calling it so that the information gets saved to the file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Memoize qw/ memoize  unmemoize /;
use Memoize::Storable;

sub ttt { 44 }

tie my %cache => 'Memoize::Storable', 'ttt.store';

memoize 'ttt', SCALAR_CACHE => [HASH => \%cache];

ttt($_) for 1..10;

unmemoize 'ttt';
```

Comment: Thanks. The docs don't say its a must to unmemoize a function.